# RHEL 7.9: rpm --eval "%dist" is now .el7_9 instead of just .el7

Tags: redhat, rpm, rhel7

Here, we've recently upgraded some of our systems from RHEL 7.8 to RHEL 7.9, and I'm facing an issue related to the "dist" returned by the rpm tool.

In some scripts, we share between RHEL7 and RHEL8 systems, we use the command: **rpm --eval "%dist"** to determine the local RHEL flavor: ".el7" or ".el8"

Starting with RHEL 7.9, the command now return: "**.el7_9**" instead of just "**.el7**".

This new behavior breaks several of our scripts. I cannot find any documentation on Red Hat site explaining this change.

I've tested the command on RHEL 8.3, and it still return only "**.el8**". So I'm very surprised by the change in 7.9.

Has anyone been confronted to this behavior too ?
Anyone knows why this change was made: bug (unlikely) or intentional ?
Any official Red Hat documentation ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Smells like a bug to me. I would report it as such.